# Directive é executada 2 vezes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Tenho a seguinte "directve":

```
app.directive('modal', ['$window', function ($window) {
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.onResizeFunction = function() {
            console.log(attrs.id);
        };

        scope.onResizeFunction();
        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
            scope.onResizeFunction();
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

O que o código acima faz é executar a função "onResizeFunction" toda vez que a janela é redimensionada.

Dentro da função tenho "console.log" que faz o trace do ID do elemento.

Quando faço resize da janela, o ID aparece 2 vezes seguidas, ou seja, a função é executada 2 vezes, mesmo existindo apenas 1 elemento no HTML com a classe "modal", onde a "directive" é aplicada.

Answer (score 1):

Diferentes *browsers* interpretam o evento de *resize* de maneiras diferentes. Alguns disparam um evento antes de iniciar o *resize*; outros, a cada evento de janela que transforma o *viewport*; outros, apenas quando o evento é finalizado - e vários implementam uma mistura dos três.

Uma das maneiras de evitar estes disparos contínuos é filtrar os eventos de acordo com uma janela de tempo:

```
var res;
window.onresize=function() {
    if (res){clearTimeout(res)};
    res = setTimeout(function(){console.log("resize triggered");},100);
};
```

Neste trecho de código, `console.log` só será invocado se nenhum outro evento de *resize* acontecer depois de 100 milisegundos.

Fonte do exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812618/window-onresize-fires-twice